# Extract first N values from a json field in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table in postgressql with column that holds an json object:

```sql
create table test (
    rec_id int generated by default as identity,
    usr_id int unique,
    format text[],
    syn_data jsonb,
    generation_date timestamptz);

insert into test values 
( 2,
  144,
  '{audio,image,text}',
  '{ "7458": { "syn_idx": [724966,125940,727242],
            "score": 5.0,
            "custom_score": 1.0},
     "1742": { "syn_idx": [119294,119321],
            "score": 5.0,
            "custom_score": 1.0},
     "38521": { "syn_idx": [654145],
            "score": 5.0,
            "custom_score": 1.0},
     "4154": { "syn_idx": [617595,348300],
            "score": 5.0,
            "custom_score": 1.0}}',
  '2023-07-19 06:29:51.584859');
```

Keys in json are random and unordered.
I need to create a function which dynamically extracts first N records from `syn_data` column in a SQL query.
For each `usr_id` there are a few rows with this kind of json data.

How can i do it for each row?

I tried a `json_each()` function and a random over, but `json_each()` returns a random ordering of keys, which is not what I expected.

For example: when I give a `2` as parameter, I'd like to get first 2 records from `syn_data` column

```json
{
  "7458": {
    "syn_idx": [724966, 125940, 727242],
    "score": 5.0,
    "custom_score": 1.0
  },
  "1742": {
    "syn_idx": [119294, 119321],
    "score": 5.0,
    "custom_score": 1.0
  }
}
```

I use PostgreSQL 14.1.

Comment: Please provide data as text, never as image. Declare your version of Postgres, and show the expected result for the given sample data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cut out all `syn_data` entries outside a target range, you can use [`jsonb - text[]` subtraction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE). [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/3OeiqBH1)

```sql
select rec_id
      ,syn_data - translate(
                    jsonb_path_query_array( syn_data
                                           ,'$.keyvalue().key
                                              ?(@.double()<$min ||
                                                @.double()>$max)'
                                           ,jsonb_build_object('min',0,
                                                               'max',2))::text
                    ,'[]'
                    ,'{}')::text[]
from test;
```

| rec_id | ?column? |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | {"1": {"score": 5.0, "syn_idx": [724966, 125940, 727242], "custom_score": 1.0}, "2": {"score": 5.0, "syn_idx": [119294, 119321], "custom_score": 1.0}} |

This `translate()`s square brackets used in a `jsonb` array resulting from [`jsonb_path_query_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.20.1.1.1) into curly brackets that allow this to be cast to `text[]` which is usable with `-`. You can also extract keys, then aggregate into a `text[]`, as shown in the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3OeiqBH1).

You could also remove all keys except the first *accidental* N entries (without "interpreting" their key, just that amount of whatever happens to be fetched first) using [`OFFSET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html) clause:

```sql
select rec_id
      ,syn_data - remove_these
from test, 
lateral (select array_agg(remove_these::text) as remove_these
         from (select jsonb_object_keys(syn_data) as remove_these 
               offset 2) as g1
        ) as g2;
```

Or the other way around, similar to what [@Charlieface suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77751479/extract-first-n-values-from-a-json-field-in-postgresql#comment137073481_77751714): extract accidental N (key,value) pairs using [`jsonb_each()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.4.1.2.1) with a [`LIMIT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html) applied, and reconstruct a jsonb out of that with a `jsonb_object_agg(k,v)`. A regular `WHERE` can replace the JSONPath filter expression while working in tandem with that `LIMIT`, which could be useful whenever you need *at most 2 out of a matching range*:

```sql
select rec_id, jsonb_object_agg(k,v)
from test, 
lateral (select * from jsonb_each(syn_data)_(k,v)
         where k::int between 0 and 2
         limit 2)
group by rec_id;
```

Comment: but i dont want to generate an additional rows for the same rec_id,, i only want to retrieve a first nth records from syn_data.

Comment: @krulon I've added an example of that at the top and in the demo. Still, I assumed first N entries based on a range their key falls in. An alternative approach would be extracting first accidental N, without looking at their key, similar to how unordered [`LIMIT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html) clause behaves. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Or try reaggregating the set of `jsonb` using `jsonb_object_agg` https://dbfiddle.uk/geuVYnXL You can also use `limit` instead of the `keyvalue()` filter

Comment: @Zegarek yes, it seems that this is a good idea. i`ve to test it on my data. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

The JSON in the `syndata` column is a dictionary.  You're looking of for the first few elements which have keys `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"` and so on.  You can generate those keys using `generate_series`, and then use the `->` operator to retrieve them from the JSON column:

```
select  syndata->(num::text)
from    my_table
cross join
        generate_series(1, 2) ser(num)
```

[Example at DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/31vT1kbb)